# SoundManager2 and Streaming URLs

Tags: soundmanager2

I am using soundmanger 2 and I am trying to implement a stream to be played when a button is pressed. However it doesn't work please see my code below:

```
soundManager.setup({ 
url: './swf/', 
preferFlash: true, 
flashVersion: 9 }) 

soundManager.createSound({ 
id: 'foo', 
url: 'http://stereo.wavestreamer.com:3056/listen.m3u?sid=1', 
type: 'audio/mp3' 
}).play();
```

When I put the url in the browser it works but it doesn't work when I try to play it from soundmanager2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you're using is pointing to an m3u file. To get it playing via SoundManager you need to point directly to the streaming URL: http://stereo.wavestreamer.com:3056/Live (extracted from the m3u file). To get other "streams" like that playing you'll need to build some javascript that makes an ajax request to get the listen.m3u file and then extracts the actual stream URL from the playlist.

Comment: I saved the m3u to my desktop and opened it in a text editor.

Comment: What I do is use Ajax/PHP to open the playlist, read the contained URL(s) and then create the SM2 sound. I recommend using [PHP's cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for reading external URLs, as you can set referer, follow redirections, etc.